# NGRX selector not updating view

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an Angular 6 app using NGRX.
My feature's state contains:

```
export class HostedApplicationsState {
    applications: Array<HostedApplicationProperties>;
    contexts:  {[appName: string]: HostedApplicationContext};
    states: {[appName: string]: ApplicationState};
    totalBadgeCount: number;    
}
```

The contexts and states are dictionaries based on the applications' names.
I have a 'dumb' list component that gets its data from the following selector:

```
export const hostedAppsListSelector = createSelector(hostedApplicationsPropertiesSelector, hostedappsAllContextsSelector, hostedappsStatesSelector,
(allProperties, contexts, states) => {
    return  allProperties && allProperties.map(properties =>
        ({properties, context: contexts[properties.applicationName], state: states[properties.applicationName]}));   
});
```

My list component is wrapped with a smart component which uses:

```
apps: Observable<Array<HostedApplication>>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.apps = this.store.pipe(select(hostedAppsListSelector)); 
}

<dbm-hosted-applications-list [apps]="apps | async"></dbm-hosted-applications-list>
```

My list is populated properly, but it does not reflect any changes made to the state once more data arrives (specifically: the 'states' are populated'). 
My reducer does replace the whole state (returning a new instance of the state).
Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your reducer may not be wired up correctly. Also could be your code related to the selector you're composing from. Can you post these things ?

Comment: Could you also post the reducer's code please.